# Windows download file - detection

Tags: python, windows

I am currently writing a python script for a project, but to move on the with the project,
I need to know where all the downloaded files/programs[exe] will go to in Windows.

I know that it will go to download folder of the user's, as long as the user did not change the default location for the downloaded folder, or they did not do **save as** to a certain location but I am asking if there is a way to locate all the files downloaded regardless of where they are saved?

Any help will be a great help, I have googled but haven't found the answer i was looking for so hoping someone here could provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a file was downloaded once-upon-a-time isn't something you can observe from the filesystem. In other words, no, you can't do this.

However, NTFS does store the fact that a file was JUST downloaded in an [alternate data stream (ADS)](https://www.howtogeek.com/70012/what-causes-the-file-downloaded-from-the-internet-warning-and-how-can-i-easily-remove-it/) which [you can read](https://github.com/RobinDavid/pyADS). This is how Windows warns you that a file was downloaded from the internet and might be dangerous.

The problem with that is, if the file is ever opened and the user says the file is safe, that data is removed. You can't know that a file was previously downloaded, only if it was downloaded and has never been opened.

If your python script needs to act upon some other files, you should ask the user where the files are, either on the command line or interactively.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response, but I dont think there is no way to do this because for example, a good antivirus will automatically detect the moment a file/program is downloaded and then let us know if it is malicious or not. Please correct if I am wrong!

Comment: The antivirus is monitoring for a file to be created in any way, it doesn't care if it was downloaded or not. We used to get viruses from copying files off floppy disks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think i was able to find what I was looking for. Now i just need to go deeper and I will get to where I wan to get for sure. Again, thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to consider.

1. You can always scan the entire drive to find the latest files. It's slow, but possible. That's your worst case scenario.
2. By extension, you can leverage the Windows file index - [Windows Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search). This will speed up searching and allow sorting by date, but is still just a faster version of the first option. In other words, it doesn't tell you anything new.
3. To get the current user's default downloads folder, consider using Windows environment variables, such as: `%USERPROFILE%\downloads`. This can greatly simplify programmatically finding the current user's folder without having to know their username.
4. (*Edited*) I had stated that there was no way to track the origin, but as pointed out in another answer it is possible to tell if it was downloaded using ADS. Specifically, the `Zone.Identifier` stream signifies that the file came from a different "security zone", i.e. not this computer. Other than that, it doesn't provide details of where it came from, but perhaps that's not important for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much, these are information that will be helpful in the long run for sure.

Comment: Don't assume the default location of the downloads directory. The current path should be queried via [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) with `FOLDERID_Downloads`, which can be called via ctypes or PyWin32 (via COM). Otherwise, you can also check the registry key "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" for a value named "Downloads" or the GUID name "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" (for me, it's currently set using the GUID name).

Comment: As I said, use environment variables *such as*. This is effectively just another variable, neither option can be *trusted* - as pointed out in the question, op is aware that the user may use "save as" when downloading. The user folder has been a convention for a very long time in Windows, it's a pretty easy to use and relatively reliable method of finding a default location.

Comment: The user shell folders in the registry are not environment variables. In organizations it's not uncommon to redirect user shell folders out of their default location in the user profile, to a UNC path or network drive, in order to minimize the size of roaming profiles that have to be synchronized at logon. The environment variables for known folders that can be relied on are fixed system variables such as "SystemRoot", "ProgramFiles", "ProgramData", "PUBLIC", and reliable user variables such as "USERPROFILE", "APPDATA", and "LOCALAPPDATA" -- but not for relocatable user shell folders.